# AutoField object has no attribute '_meta - field._meta.verbose_name

Tags: python, django

```
def export_as_xls(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    """
    Generic xls export admin action.
    """
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        raise PermissionDenied
    opts = modeladmin.model._meta

    wb = Workbook()
    ws0 = wb.add_sheet('0')
    col = 0
    field_names = []
    # write header row
    for field in opts.fields:
        ws0.write(0, col, field._meta.verbose_name)
        field_names.append(field._meta.verbose_name)
        col = col + 1
```

If I try export to xls I have this error:

> 'AutoField' object has no attribute '_meta'

With: `field.name` this working but I need verbose name

Answer (score 0):

For Fields you should just use `field.verbose_name`

_meta is available on Model instances but not Field instances